# Linear Programming Problem 3

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

A paper mill manufactures its paper in standard reels 6 metres wide and cuts these to the widths required by its customers. This may result in some waste, which must be discarded as there is no room to store it.
It has received the following orders:

- 2.7m wide, 30 reels ordered
- 2.1m wide, 150 reels ordered
- 1.65m wide, 65 reels ordered

My working out;

To begin this problem I wanted to find out how many different options there were to cut the reels in order to minimise wastage. 
Ways denoted by pi, Width (in metres), Wastage

p1  3*1.65=4.95, wastage =  1.05

p2  2*1.65 + 2.1=5.4 wastage=   0.6

p3  1.65 + 2*2.1=5.85 wastage=  0.15

p4  2.1 + 2.7=4.8 wastage=  1.2

p5  2*2.7=5.4 wastage=  0.6

p6  2.7 + 2*1.65=6 wastage= 0

Decision variables:

Let x1 be the number of times we use p1, x2 be the number of times we use p2, x3 be the number of times we use p3 and so on.

**Constraints:**
***I don't think my constraints are right? please can some one help me***

$3x_1 + 2x_2+ x_3 + 2x_6 = 65$  (to satisfy order of 1.65m)

$x_2 + 2x_3 + x_4 = 150$             (to satisfy order of 2.1m)

$x_4 + 2x_5 + x_6 = 30$               (to satisfy order of 2.7m)

$x_i \geq 0 \ \ \forall \ i=1,..,6$

Objective function:

We want to minimise waste so;

$$Min \ \       Z= 1.05x_1 + 0.6x_2 + 0.15x_3 + 1.2x_4 + 0.6 x_5$$

To solve this problem I used the Solver function on Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the variables of the options you´ve introduced: $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,p_6$

Then we want to minimize the waste:

$$\texttt{Min} \ = 1.05\cdot p_1 + 0.6\cdot p_2 + 0.15\cdot p_3 + 1.2\cdot p_4 + 0.6\cdot  p_5$$

I just changed the notation from $x_i$ to $p_i$.

I summarize your options in a table:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}  \hline & 2.7 & 2.1 & 1.65 & \texttt{waste} \\ \hline p_1 &0&0&3&1.05  \\ \hline p_2&0&1&2&0.6 \\ \hline p_3 &0 &2&1 &0.15 \\ \hline p_4 &1&1&0&1.2 \\ \hline p_5&2&0&0&0.6 \\ \hline p_6& 1&0&2& 0 \\ \hline \end{array}$$

Now we have the constraint that we need at least $30$ reels with a width of $2.7 \  m$. Just read off the coefficient of the column which is lables as $2.7$

$1p_4+2p_5+p_6\geq 30$

Similar for the constraints of reels with the widths $2.1$ and $1.65$

$p_2+2p_3+1p_4\geq 150$

$ 3p_1+2p_2+1p_3+2p_6\geq 65 $

Finally the domain of the variables: $p_i\in \mathbb N_0 \ \forall i=1,2,...,6$

Comment: Note that $p_i$ are defined as integers.

Comment: i did the constraints as equal and got 90 reels needed but a wastage of like 30m, but if you do it with a greater than or equal to constraint you get a wastage of 11.25m but need 105 reels? obviously 90 reels is less than 105 but what is the correct solution? @callculus

Comment: Give me 45 min to calculate it with excel.

Comment: i also need to do the solution if the person ordering the 2.1 m reels were to increase their order by 10 and by 20 reels. also if i do it with equal constraints it doesn't work for 170, excel can't find a feasible solution but works for 160.  If you use greater than it solves or parts of q but its a lot higher than 90? @callculus

Comment: @CharlotteSacks $p_6$ has no waste.  It might be  a good idea to act like it has a little waste. Since it does matter how many of $p_6$ we make. The waste is not the only criteria. I set $w_6=0.01$The solution of the original problem is $(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,p_5,p_6)=(0,0,75,0,0,30)$ The total waste is indeed 11.25 and the LHS of the constraints are $(30,150,135)$.

Comment: @CharlotteSacks As I said use inequalities and give $p_6$ a little waste. If $w_6=0$ the value of $p_6$ can be $100000$. This would not be an appropriate solution.

Comment: @CharlotteSacks If you set $w_6=0.01$ or something similar you have to subtract $p_6^*\cdot w_6 $, where $p_6^*$ is the optimal value for $p_6$ of the solver.

Comment: thank you for your help :) @callculus I understand it now

Comment: @CharlotteSacks You´re welcome. I would be nice if you mark the question as  answered by clicking on the question mark.

Comment: done @callculus

Comment: would you be able to help with a binary problem? @callculus

Comment: @CharlotteSacks Thanks for accepting. Maybe I´m able to help you. The best strategy is to post an new question. In this case anybody in the world is able to notice your question. But of course I´ll have a look at it.

Comment: hey someone else calculated this on the forum and got a different answer @callculus

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2978398/how-to-solve-cutting-stock-problem-by-hand-or-on-excel     @callculus

Comment: @CharlotteSacks I don´t think that there the objective function is right. We want to minimize the waste. In this part a totally agree with your attempt.