# possible bin packing question

Tags: algorithms, mixed-integer-programming

what is known: you are given 3 packs of boards of different lengths. ie pack A is 3.9m, B is 3m and C 2.4m  and an arbitrary distance to cover, d. how do I pose and then solve this question?

3.9A + 3B + 2.4C ~= d ??

obviously A, B and C are positive, integer values and the aim is to get as close to d as possible.

n.b this is real life problem I encounter most days and normally solve by trial and error

Comment: Have a look to the answer of this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2976665/144421).

Comment: @callculus the linked post is not quite the same problem.  Here, there is only one target, and you can over- or undersatisfy it.

Comment: @RobPratt Yes, it is not exactly the same problem. But it is very similar and the method can be adjusted. I also  have the suspicion that more than one piece has to be covered.

Comment: @callculus my problem is similar but the width has no impact its a predetermined number of boards wide and then say 9m long. The answer to this would B = 3; A, C = 0 but I don't know how to use math to do it.

Comment: You minimize $d$, w.r.t.  $3.9A+3B+2.4C-9=d$, where $A,B,C \in \mathbb N_0$

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem via mixed integer linear programming as follows.  Let $S\ge 0$ and $T \ge 0$ be surplus and slack variables, respectively.  The problem is to minimize $S+T$ subject to
$$3.9 A + 3 B + 2.4 C - S + T = d.$$

Comment: hi thank you! I've been trying to solve using this but I don't know what my constraints would be or how I attempt it with 0 constraints.